# How to separate angular + ejs app from node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

I have web application which is developed using ejs + angularJs 1.0 and running in node server. Since these ejs + angular provides only static files, I want to make my app running in webserver. Currently the URL mapping is done in node app.js, hence if we load the URL it renders the html from the ejs. For more information, I have added node app.js configuration:

```
app.set('title', wsConfig.title); 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.engine('.html', ejs.__express); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public')); // Set the views path

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
if (req.url.substr(-1) == '/' && req.url.length > 1)
    res.redirect(301, req.url.slice(0, -1));
else
    next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('login', { title: wsConfig.title });
});

app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: wsConfig.title });
});
```

Hence I need to build a dist folder with js and rendered ejs files instead using node server for rendering. So that I will deploy this dist directory in web server. I thought of using webpack to accomplish this. Please give our suggestions.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you still want to use Angular? You mention serving static pages, but there would be no reason to use Angular for a static site.

Comment: Yes, I need to use angular. Sorry, what I actually try to say is angular is not doing any database calls here, it just bind the data using Ajax calls